# How do you access the $on, $emit, $broadcast methods with Controller as syntax?

Tags: angularjs

Using `$scope` it's easy to emit an event or watch for one.

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("app")
        .controller("Ctrl", [
            "$scope",
            CtrlDefinition
        ]);

    function CtrlDefinition($scope) {
        $scope.$on("change", listenForChange);

        function listenForChange(data) {
            //do something
        }
    }
})();
```

But if I try to use `var vm = this` syntax, I'm warned that `$on`, `$emit`, and `$broadcast` are not methods of `this`. How can I access them? Do I still need to inject `$scope` in the controller definition?

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("app")
        .controller("Ctrl", CtrlDefinition);

    function CtrlDefinition() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.$on("change", listenForChange); //$on is not a method of vm
    }

})();
```

You could do something like this, but wouldn't it defeat the purpose of not having to use `$scope` at all?

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("app")
        .controller("Ctrl", [
            "$scope",
            CtrlDefinition
        ]);

    function CtrlDefinition($scope) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.scope = $scope;
        vm.scope.$on("change", listenForChange);
    }

})();
```

How can you access watchers with controller as syntax?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In order to use anything that exists on `$scope`, you are forced to inject `$scope`.  It's unfortunately that straightforward, which is a shortcoming of the "as" syntax.

The good news however is that injecting `$scope` alongside `this` does not change how the controller as syntax functions, it simply gives you access to all of the event management that lives on  `$scope`.

It's worth noting that this is one of the primary reasons for what is coming in Angular 2.0...there is a real problem and discrepancy between `$scope` and the "Controller as" syntax that was bolted on to solve scoping issues in views.

Comment: I see...I'm not too fluent in the difference between `$scope` and `this`, though your comment tempts me just to use `var vm = $scope`.

Comment: `this` is a reserved keyword in javascript that refers to the immediate scope (in this case, the function `CtrlDefinition`.  Although you COULD do that, you would also potentially expose data that is not relevant to your controller, which is why best practice dictates `var vm = this;`.

Comment: @DanielLizik I would definitely not use ```vm = $scope``` you would simply be attaching everything from your controller to the $scope, which completely defeats the purpose of using vm or $ctrl.