# How to use $emit / $ on without using $scope?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using angularJS 1.3 in my app, and according to best practices of using angular, instead of `$scope` we use `var self = this` . Is it possible using `$on` / `$emit` without injecting `$scope` / `rootScope`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as David L answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32015667/how-do-you-access-the-on-emit-broadcast-methods-with-controller-as-syntax)

> In order to use anything that exists on $scope, you are forced to
>   inject $scope. It's unfortunately that straightforward, which is a
>   shortcoming of the "as" syntax.
>
> The good news however is that injecting $scope alongside this does not
>   change how the controller as syntax functions, it simply gives you
>   access to all of the event management that lives on  $scope.
>
> It's worth noting that this is one of the primary reasons for what is
>   coming in Angular 2.0...there is a real problem and discrepancy
>   between $scope and the "Controller as" syntax that was bolted on to
>   solve scoping issues in views.