# How to call function in ng-view controller from parent?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having difficulty calling a function in a child controller in an ng-view from my parent controller.

currently my html has something along the lines of

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="bodyController as bc" ng-init="bc.init()">
  <ng-view><ng-view>
</body>
```

My JS has 2 controllers, the body controller and the view controller. I want to call a function from the view controller in the body controller but my $on and $broadcast functions are coming up as undefined and not running.

```
app.controller('bodyController', bodyController);
app.controller('viewController', viewController);

function bodyController(){
  var vm = this;
  vm.init = function(){
    vm.$broadcast('load')
  }

function viewController(){
  var vm = this;
  vm.$on('load', functionToCall)
  }
```

I thought the issue might be that the view controller wasn't loaded yet so i couldnt call a function from it. so I instead tried emitting a signal from the view controller on its ng-init that the parent bodyController would hear and then broadcast back a new signal so that the function ran but that wasn't working either. I've tried searching through stack overflow for a while now and either can't find a relevant answer or the answers are over my head. I'd appreciate any help greatly.

Comment: Hi, as far as i recall, aren't you supposed to inject the `$...` in your controlelr methods signature. I'm far from expert in Angular though

Comment: Have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37717493/usage-of-broadcast-emit-and-on-in-angularjs

Comment: you probably have to use $scope.$broadcast & $scope.$on

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32015667/how-do-you-access-the-on-emit-broadcast-methods-with-controller-as-syntax

Comment: Thanks Charlie! that's very helpful